# I am struck in trouble while using Promise to get away from asynchronous effect

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am using node.js and mongoose to make an application which could help users to parse specified words in a text. But it can not work synchronously. Following is my code:

```
app.post("/detector/result", function(req, res) {
  var result = {};
  var text = req.body.paragraph;
  var text2 = text.replace(/,/g, '');
  var text3 = text2.replace(/\./g, '');
  var textArr = text3.split(" ");

  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    textArr.forEach(function(word) {
      grewords.find({
        English: word
      }, function(err, greword) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          if (!(greword.length < 1 || greword == undefined)) {
            console.log(word);
            console.log(result);
            if (word in result) {
              result[word] = result[word] + 1;
            } else {
              result[word] = 1;
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
    resolve(result);
  }).then(function(r) {
    console.log(r);
    res.render("detectorresult", {
      grewordObj: r
    });
  });
});
```

When I run my code, it still shows in shell:

```
{}
adversary
{}
adventitious
{ adversary: 1 }
assertive
{ adversary: 1, adventitious: 1 }
```

Why `{}` still shows firstly in stead of showing lastly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The first `{}` comes from the last `console.log(r)`. `word` is every element in the array `textArr`. I want to run the `forEach` function at first, then pass the object `result` to `grewordObj`, so that I can use it in my ejs file. But in fact, it still can not work because of asynchronous effect --- `console.log(r)` runs firstly before the finish of `forEach` function.

Comment: Conceptually here, you don't "get away from asynchronous effect".   Instead, you learn how to program correctly with it, how to manage it, how to coordinate asynchronous operations with other code.  This is one of the first major things you need to do when doing server programming in node.js.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand JavaScript nature(Asynchronous programming). You can not call many times `resolve` or `reject` function, you may use `Promise.all()` function, following example may help you

```
app.post('/detector/result', function (req, res) {
    var result = {};
    var text = req.body.paragraph;
    var text2 = text.replace(/,/g, '');
    var text3 = text2.replace(/\./g, '');
    var textArr = text3.split(' ');

    Promise.all(textArr.map(function (word) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            grewords.find({
                English: word
            }, function (err, greword) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    if (!(greword.length < 1 || greword == undefined)) {
                        console.log(word);
                        console.log(result);
                        if (word in result) {
                            result[word] = result[word] + 1;
                        } else {
                            result[word] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    resolve(greword);
                }
            });
        });
    })).then(function (r) {
        console.log('Final result ', r); // r will be an array of object as we rerturned object in each iteration 
        console.log('Final result ', result);
        res.render('detectorresult', {
            grewordObj: result
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Got error ', err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, which is so helpful and enlightening. Also, the `Promise.all` works perfectly for my application!